# Jenkins fetch map value on condition and pass to shared library as parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I've a script like as below for jenkins shared library and I would like to get users's slackID according to the user's email adress for passing this ID as parameter to the function.

How can I fetch the slackID according to the email address and then pass this value as parameter? What is the best way to do this ?

Here is the shared-library script.

```
users = [
    bennytheball: [
        git: 'benny.ball@alley.way',
        slack: '12345ABCD'
    ],
    choochoo: [
        git: 'choo.choo@alley.way',
        slack: 'ABCD12345'
    ],
    topcat: [
        git: 'top.cat@alley.way',
        slack: 'U9X76IJYA'
    ]
]

String email = sh(script: 'git show -s --pretty=%ae', returnStdout: true).trim()
def sendBuildStatusOverSlack(String authorSlackID = null) {
         .....
    }
```

Project Jenkinsfile

```
sendNotifications(authorSlackID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the according slack id like this

```
users.findAll { _, contact -> contact.git == email }
     .collect { _, contact -> contact.slack }
```

Comment: shall I run this in jenkinsfile or shared library ? What should be the proper way ?

Comment: can I run all this script in shared library and pass this value as parameter and then run groovy script without parameter ? What should be the proper way to do that ?

Comment: doesn't really matter. But it seems pretty specific to me. I'd put it in the pipeline.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass this value as parameter and then run groovy script without parameter"?

Comment: I mean my groovyscript name is sendNotification... In jenkins file can I use this without parameter ?

Comment: Why would you want it to use it without parameter, when this script needs the data?